# How i can add custom view on tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

[image]

i'm need add two vertical line on tabbar item. how i can make this? Thank.

add next code:

```
var imageLeft: UIImageView?
var imageRight: UIImageView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let grayColor = UIColor(red: 170/255, green: 170/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1.0)
    let leftLine = (tabBar.frame.width/2) - ((tabBar.frame.width/5)/2)
    let rightLine = (tabBar.frame.width/2) + ((tabBar.frame.width/5)/2)
    imageLeft = UIImageView(image: createImage(color: grayColor, size: tabBar.frame.size, x: leftLine))
    imageRight = UIImageView(image: createImage(color: grayColor, size: tabBar.frame.size, x: rightLine))
    tabBar.addSubview(imageLeft!)
    tabBar.addSubview(imageRight!)
}

func createImage(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, x: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: x, y: 5, width: 1, height: tabBar.frame.height - 11)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

my result:

[image]

Comment: I told you in my answer that you needed to modify the code to get a good result. What you'd do is calculate the `CGRect`s that you want to show, and draw them in the createImage function. Then add them to the tabBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can subclass UITabBarController and add a UIImageView at the location you want it to be:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var image: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        image = UIImageView(image: createImage(color: UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.66, blue:0.24, alpha:1.0), size: tabBarItemSize, lineHeight: 4))
        tabBar.addSubview(image!)
    }

    func createImage(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height - lineHeight, width: size.width, height: lineHeight )
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

You'll need to modify this for your needs and calculate the location you'd like it to be at, but this should help. I shine some more light on this in [an article I wrote](https://medium.com/@JillevdWeerd/bringing-animation-to-uitabbarcontroller-1b8780ced374).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom tab bar.
Here is a tutorial on how do make one: https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

Or you can find a library that will do it for you on Github